# Using two separate relational indexes in elasticsearch is sense or not?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, relation

I have two relational mysql tables and i need to store these data to elasticsearch.
I stored like this and i wanted to ask you if there is a best way or not :

```
POST categories/_doc
{
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "Phones"
}

POST categories/_doc
{
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "TV"
}

PUT products
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST products/_doc
{
   "id" : 3
   "category_id" : 1
   "name" : "IPhone 5S",
   "attributes" : [
    {
      "color" : "red",
      "stock" : 4
    },
    {
      "color" : "blue",
      "stock" : 2
    }
   ]
}

POST products/_doc
{
   "id" : 5
   "category_id" : 2
   "name" : "Samsung TV",
   "attributes" : [
    {
      "color" : "red",
      "stock" : 2
    },
    {
      "color" : "yellow",
      "stock" : 4
    }
   ]
}
```

And i use two queries for searching :

I firstly search on categories index after that i send category id values to products index

```
GET products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "attributes.color": [
                  "red",
                  "blue"
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "category_id": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can you please share your comments about this topic ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to do like this, since you will have a really difficult time doing sorting and pagination on your application. In Elasticsearch is really important to flat the data for performance reasons and store it in one index, if you have really separated content you can have them in multiple indices. Also keep these points in mind:

1. Elasticsearch is not a relational database. You will not be able to Join indices as you used to join Tables
2. Denormalization is not natural but is a key for efficiency in an Elasticsearch application.
3. Thinking of your data mapping at the early beginning will allow your
   app to fly for years.

Comment: After searching, i combine two results with PHP code.
That will be a problem ?

Comment: How would you handle sorting by category if you have thousands of categories and prodcuts?

Comment: What do you recomment ?
Something like that ? 

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qPn9pYrNzQ/

Comment: The other way around. Add the category name along with the category ID to all your products. It's unlikely that those names change that often, right?

Comment: Yes, it is better to put all in product index.

Comment: Something like that ? 

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Vs26fyGQ2J/

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go